# QCamera get error "mesa-loader failed to retrieve device information"

Tags: webcam, qt

Qt test code:

```
QCamera* camera = new QCamera;
auto viewfinder = new QCameraViewfinder();
camera->setViewfinder(viewfinder);
viewfinder->show();
camera->start();
```

Output:

```
mesa-loader failed to retrieve device information 
mesa-loader failed to retrieve device information 
mesa-loader failed to retrieve device information 

org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
```

after that the whole system will fast auto "reboot". all process stopped.

Reffered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49830493/webgl-does-not-work-properly-on-raspberry-pi-chromium-browser

But I already enabled OpenGL driver. and the camera interface.

I think the camera could correctly get the video frame, but cannot render in Qt.

Answer (score 0):

“mesa-loader failed to retrieve device information” is an expected debug message if you have an ancient libdrm, but is not an indication of anything actually being wrong.  You'll have to look into the QT support for the camera (hopefully you can just use the v4l2 device).